# CSS div and :hover positions

Tags: html, css

On my site : Dev.stevehamber.com

I am trying to get the image "New Page" (currently behind the slider) to be positioned outside it's current DIV, overlapping the top right hand corner, but so that it also moves with the Auto margin of the main content.  Can't seem to figure out how, with out it being either behind something or not following the auto margin of the container.

I have also had problems with the :hover attribute.  Experimenting with fixed position Divs I have noticed the image/background doesn't change on the bottom right hand corner of the fixed "F",  is this something to do with positioning too? :/

I tried Googling this but couldn't explain myself in 1 sentence, so I hope this makes sense. Ha!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS, add `z-index`, like this:

```css
img.newpage {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably suggest a negative `right` (perhaps `right: -25px`) to get the desired effect, but this is probably the way to go about it. There's one of the "slides" that messes with z-index too, but that should be an easy fix.

Comment: I totally agree with you! And I think that if he adds these lines it's perfect
margin-right: -20px;
margin-top: -20px;

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated.  Can I ask why margin-right: -20px is used, yet margin left doesn't work?  I am a designer diving head first in to coding so it's still a little confusing.

Comment: No problem mate!
Have a look here and see the use of negative margins
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0):

Give the F a high z-index to make it be on top

Answer (score 0):

Put the newpage.png in a div that's on top of the slider div. Put both of those div's inside another div; assign the css auto-margin attributes to this parent div.

So something like

```
<div id="slider">
  <div id="slidercontent"><!-- in here, put the slider -->
  </div>
  <div id="newpage"><!-- make newpage.png the background image of this-->
  </div>
</div>
```

As for the hover; please explain a bit more thoroughly, it seems to work fine with me. You mean the facebook button right? (its positioned top-left in my FF btw)